# Clarification on webviews

Tags: android, android-webview

> ...
>   However, you shouldn't develop an 
>   Android app simply as a means to 
>   view your website. Rather, the web 
>   pages you embed in your app should 
>   be designed especially for that 
>   environment.

I was reading this in android documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/best-practices

I don't totally understand what the last line means. I know that web view is used to load urls in android activity.
Web view simply loads a url in app. But can it be used in another way. Can anyone explain me what does it mean and how can I do that? Please provide some details.

Comment: Which code are you talking about? @user1241241

Answer (score 0):

> *However, you shouldn't develop an  Android app simply as a means to  view your website.*

If the app is for viewing your website, we can as well use the browser for that.

> *Rather, the web  pages you embed in your app should  be designed especially for that  environment.*

Say there is a terms and conditions screen in your web site that you don't want to develop for mobile apps. This single screen can be loaded on a web view inside your android app.